# IBM Worklight - Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am a beginner to work on IBMWorklight.I am getting this error: 
Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
When i right click - Run As- Invoke Worklight Procedure on adapter name: SQLAdapter1.
My SQLAdapter1.xml file has below mentioned coding:

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
                <dataSourceDefinition>
                    <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prem</url>
                    <user>myPassword</user>
                    <password>myPassword</password>
                </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
    </connectivity>
    <procedure name="getAccounts" />
```

My SQLAdapter1-impl.js file has below mentioned coding

```
var getAccountsTransactionsStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
" select * from accounts"
);
function getAccounts(){
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
preparedStatement : getAccountsTransactionsStatement ,
parameters : []
});
}
```

Any help.Urgent please.Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: have you found any solution of yours problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add the MySQL Connector/J driver .jar file to your project's server\lib folder.
You can download the driver from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mehul im sure in his project he didnt refer the mysql.jar file. Code is perfect so there is no issue in code.

Comment: @RED.Skull, added minor changes to your answer.

Comment: @IdanAdar Okey. i forgot to provide link to sql jar file.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34670/ibm-worklight-developer-phonegap ... for worklight developers.